# VSTO web interaction

Tags: web-services, web, vsto

In PHP I can use this code:

```
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$location1&      destinations=$location2&mode=bicycling&language=en-EN&sensor=false";       
        $data = @file_get_contents($url);       
        $obj = json_decode($data);        
        $arr = (array)$obj;
```

to get an array of values that return the distance between 2 locations.

Is this kind of web interaction possible with VSTO? I have Googled high and low and nothing I search is giving me any results to work with.

Ergo, I think I am missing something.

Comment: What language? `VB.NET`? `C#`? Have a look in this [Google Maps .NET API](http://gmaps.codeplex.com/), I think it could be helpful.

Comment: OK, what about this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20720172/getting-driving-distance-with-google-maps-api-and-ssis-package-in-c-sharp
Read the accepted answer, it looks very similar to your goal.

Comment: No, it didn't work at all. There are missing braces and overridden methods with the wrong return type.

Comment: How about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490599/parsing-json-rest-api-response-in-c-sharp

Comment: No. That is about how to parse a JSON response, not how to get the response in the first place.

Comment: First lines are about getting response: client.BaseUrl = "https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com";
request.Resource = "/v1/chats/create.json?key=" + cac.AppCode.ToString();
request.Method = Method.POST;
request.AddUrlSegment("appkey", "key");
var response = client.Execute(request);